# Kubernetes: required flag(s) "image" not set

Tags: kubernetes, openproject

Kuberentes returns the following error:

```
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~/Dokumente$ kubectl run -f open-project.yaml
Error: required flag(s) "image" not set
```

I want to create Open Project based on a Kubernetes On-Prem installation. There are [references for docker](https://www.openproject.org/docker/); however I would like to use Kubernetes on top of it to get more familar with it. It's important to keep things working after a reboot of my host. Therefore I want to persistent the open project configuration. Docker references this by adding a volume (-v option):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata \
  -v /var/lib/openproject/static:/var/openproject/assets \
  openproject/community:8
```

My Kubernetes file looks like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: open-project-pod
  labels:
    environment: production
spec:
  containers:
    - name: open-project-container
      image: openproject/community:8
      ports:
        - name: open-project
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/openproject"
          name: data
      livenessProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 600
        timeoutSeconds: 1
  volumes:
    - name: data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: open-project-storage-claim
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
```

Error: required flag(s) "image" not set

Comment: It's `apply`, not `run` you should be using here.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is applied and available via kubectl get pods. How do I start the pod? kubctl run pod open-project-pod throws the image error once again.

Comment: I'd advise maybe you go through the Kuberenetes tutorial (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/) to get more familiar with how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it gives a good understanding!

Answer (score 6):

The correct command is `kubectl apply -f open-project.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

the full docker path in your kubernetes manifest file should be docker.io/openproject/community